# Find array with a certain value multidimensional array wordpress in_array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

i am running a wordpress website that use wpml which is giving me loads of issues trying to run a query on tags on my translated posts which are in welsh cy.

So what i am trying to do is a little hack that will allow me to query all posts and locate the post with a specific tags using wordpresses function get_the_tags();

I am trying to use in_array which doesnt seem to work on the multidimesional array that wordpress outputs, here is the array from a print_r();

```
>   Array (
>     [629] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [term_id] => 629
>             [name] => bulletin
>             [slug] => bulletin
>             [term_group] => 0
>             [term_taxonomy_id] => 630
>             [taxonomy] => post_tag
>             [description] => 
>             [parent] => 0
>             [count] => 2
>             [object_id] => 19838
>         )
> 
>     [631] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [term_id] => 631
>             [name] => english2
>             [slug] => english2
>             [term_group] => 0
>             [term_taxonomy_id] => 632
>             [taxonomy] => post_tag
>             [description] => 
>             [parent] => 0
>             [count] => 1
>             [object_id] => 19838
>         )
> 
> ) Array (
>     [629] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [term_id] => 629
>             [name] => bulletin
>             [slug] => bulletin
>             [term_group] => 0
>             [term_taxonomy_id] => 630
>             [taxonomy] => post_tag
>             [description] => 
>             [parent] => 0
>             [count] => 2
>             [object_id] => 19842
>         )
> 
>     [630] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [term_id] => 630
>             [name] => english1
>             [slug] => english1
>             [term_group] => 0
>             [term_taxonomy_id] => 631
>             [taxonomy] => post_tag
>             [description] => 
>             [parent] => 0
>             [count] => 1
>             [object_id] => 19842
>         )
> 
> ) Array (
>     [0] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [term_id] => 633
>             [name] => welsh2
>             [slug] => welsh2
>             [term_group] => 0
>             [term_taxonomy_id] => 634
>             [taxonomy] => post_tag
>             [description] => 
>             [parent] => 0
>             [count] => 1
>         )
> 
> ) Array (
>     [0] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [term_id] => 632
>             [name] => welsh1
>             [slug] => welsh1
>             [term_group] => 0
>             [term_taxonomy_id] => 633
>             [taxonomy] => post_tag
>             [description] => 
>             [parent] => 0
>             [count] => 1
>         )
> 
> )
```

And here is my code i only want it to located the array with the name welsh1 which is the last one in the array.

```
  // Global calls to the database
  global $wpdb;

  // Runs a query to get all results from the wp_posts table
  $all = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts" );

  // loops through each one   
  foreach($all as $v){

      $tags = get_the_tags($v->ID);

      if (in_array('welsh1', $tags)) {
        echo "'ph' was found\n";
      }

      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($tags);
      echo "</pre>";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$tags is an array of objects, not a multidimensional array.

The following code should identify the string `welsh1`

```
foreach($tags as $tag){
  if ($tag->name == "welsh1" || $tag->slug == "welsh1"){
     echo "'ph' was found\n";
     break;//this line makes the foreach loop end after first success.
  }
}
```